# Git project permission denied

Tags: git, github

I ran

```
git clone git@github.com:{username}/{project}.git
```

fatal: Could not rerad from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

so:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

No such file or directory,
hmm...

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

WARNIG: UNPORTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!
Permissions 0775 for .... are too open.

Comment: I think you should follow the official guide and make sure you do each step ~ https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: Also `id_rsa` is a file, not a directory. You'll need to remove the one you made before continuing

Answer (score 1):

To complemet the comments and the [steps to follow](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), keep in mind ssh`-add` is only needed if you have created a private key protected with a passphrase.

If you use

```
cd ~
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
cd .ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

That will create `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, the latter (public key) is to be registered in your GitHub profile settings.

Test the access with `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to ensure yu are correctly authenticated.